# gerrit/git setup messed up when network disconnected in the middle. How to abandon the partial commits?

Tags: git, gerrit

I was pushing my changes from local git repo to Gerrit using "git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master" when my network disconnected.

Now when I try to rerun it, I get:

Counting objects: 40, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (36/36), 2.23 MiB, done.
Total 36 (delta 4), reused 5 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
To ssh://@:29418/scaligent.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (change 57 closed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://@:29418/scaligent.git'

How do I clean up the state?

Comment: Does it work if you add `--force` to your push?

Comment: sometimes you need to connect by ssh and go in scaligent.git then do `git config core.bare true`, if it was not already set like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message said everything

> [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (change 57 closed)

It's not caused by git push. Normally you get this error in such a case:

- Push local commit to server as change 57 patchset 1
- Modify something & git commit -amend
- Someone(include yourself) click submit or abandon button in gerrit (which will close change 57)
- Run git push again

Gerrit found you try to add a new patchset to a closed change, so revert the push.

Now you can clean it up by following step:

- (optional) git branch -b backup
- git fetch origin
- git reset origin/master
- git commit -a
- git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master